# Warning!! We need to rescue Mr. Greg

Tags: story, steganography, computer-puzzle

Greg, our Server Security Admin, was locked up today in his own Server Room. (Yeah, quite crazy I know). The guy had forgotten the password to unlock his door. Fortunately he had saved the password on his laptop. He takes a sigh of relief and sits down on his chair, opens up his laptop and gets into the folder which has 6 files.

Now, he has a bad memory and is unable to recollect how to find the password. He has emailed me those 6 files. Can you help me find the password so that I can help our dear friend get out of the room?

Leaving the files right here for you -

**unused_1.txt**

```
f = 10
s = 20
a = 30
d = 40

sum = f + a + d

print(sum)
```

**unused_2.txt**

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int m = "hello";
    int a = "how are";
    int y = "you";
    int t = "world";

    String txt = m + a + y;

    System.out.println(txt);
  }
}
```

**unused_3.txt**

```
const e = "Hello, world!";
const a = "Hello, planet!";
const parts = a.split(", ");

console.log(parts);
```

**unused_4.txt**

```
fun main() {
    val a = "Help help!"
    val b = "Dont help!"
    val c = "Please help!"
    val bCount = b.length
    val cCount = c.length

    println("The string '$b' has $bCount characters.")
    println("The string '$c' has $cCount characters.")
}
```

**unused_5.txt**

```
using System;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string hostName = "www.google.com";
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        PingReply reply = ping.Send(hostName);
        
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) {
            string l = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Ping to " + hostName + " was successful. Response time: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms.");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping to " + hostName + " failed. Status: " + reply.Status);
        }
    }
}
```

**get_password.py**

```
def decrypt(msg: str, password: str) -> str:
    key = generate_key(password)
    decrypted = ""
    for i in range(len(msg)):
        char = msg[i]
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        decrypted += chr((ord(char) - ord(key_c) + 256) % 256)
    return decrypted

def generate_key(password: str) -> str:
    key = ""
    for i in range(len(password)):
        key += chr(ord(password[i]) % 256)
    return key

encrypted_message = "ÇÜÊÜ™“ÞÔæ„‚àÞƒÚÕÉá”ÙÉÑ@ŠÖ×”‰ÕŒ“ÓÚÔÊ¼âÌ®¬ƒŽiÕ˜"
key = "enter_the_key_you_found_here" + " & get blocked"

decrypted_message = decrypt(encrypted_message, key)
print("Decrypted message:", decrypted_message)
```

**Update**:

So, I called back Greg and told him that the puzzling stack exchange is having hard time interpreting the ASCII codes in his file. Well, he did have a backup for situations like these and have send me another file. I guess this should help us getting him out.

**get_password_backup.py**

```
CHARACTER_SET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}|;':\",.<>/?\\ "

def generate_key(password: str) -> str:
    key = ""
    for i in range(len(password)):
        key += CHARACTER_SET[ord(password[i]) % len(CHARACTER_SET)]
    return key

def encrypt(msg: str, password: str) -> str:
    key = generate_key(password)
    encrypted = ""
    for i in range(len(msg)):
        char = msg[i]
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        char_index = CHARACTER_SET.index(char)
        key_c_index = CHARACTER_SET.index(key_c)
        encrypted_index = (char_index + key_c_index) % len(CHARACTER_SET)
        encrypted += CHARACTER_SET[encrypted_index]
    return encrypted

def decrypt(msg: str, password: str) -> str:
    key = generate_key(password)
    decrypted = ""
    for i in range(len(msg)):
        char = msg[i]
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        char_index = CHARACTER_SET.index(char)
        key_c_index = CHARACTER_SET.index(key_c)
        decrypted_index = (char_index - key_c_index) % len(CHARACTER_SET)
        decrypted += CHARACTER_SET[decrypted_index]
    return decrypted

print (decrypt("^EmdEG4YGwOJoLunCuHLkooZTKjlLUGroGh_J=8jxT(S+kEOCW","enter the key you found here" + " & get locked"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hearing back from Greg about the unfortunate encoding issues, we now have the solution:

> The names of the unused variables in each of the 5 "unused_" files spell out "steal".

Using that as the key in the 6th file and running it in an online Python interpreter reveals that

> The password to unlock the door is $n00finGm@chinE

I hope Greg gets to take the rest of Friday off for the trouble!

(for specifics, I have used this one here, but any would work I think:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/)

Comment: Well, you are almost there. But lol, looks like Stackexchange is bad at handling ASCII as well. I realized it only after posting when it ate up lot of characters from the string while the preview mode was just fine. I have communicated the same to Greg and we have an update :)

Comment: @Techidiot yes, after running the latest file with the key the password is revealed :-)

Comment: Yay! Greg sends his best regards :)